# How do I get a td background color to stretch from left to right, not just the table width, in html & css?

Tags: css, html, layout, html-table

I'm creating a page where a want to list a number of items. To make it more readable, I want to change the background color of every second item. I want that background color to stretch all the way from left to right, like the browser window.

At the moment the table containing these elements has a width of 950px, so the td color is only 950px. How can I make it wider while at the same time maintaining the 950px width for the text?

The page I'm working on is http://www.spanish-bookworld.com/delete-footer.html

Comment: are your really writing a table layout? http://learnlayout.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution you envision is next to impossible.

You need to make the table the full width of the page and then wrap the content of each table cell in a wrapper that has a width of 950px and that is horizontally centered within the cell.

Using a table for this layout is a poor choice. Each table row is a stand alone unit and could be marked up as a block level element (div) with child elements.  Large tables tend to load and render more slowly, so avoid them unless you are displaying tabulated data.

Comment: Getting rid of the table is clearly the solution. Unfortunately my knowledge of CSS is not good enough at the moment for that.I'd love to find someone to help me with it, obviously for a fee.

Comment: Some of the other solutions posted show a non-table approach to achieving an equivalent layout, so they may offer you a starting point and are well worth a careful look.

Comment: The page I'm actually working on is quite a bit more complicated than the one I mentioned above. For the moment I'm going to make the background colors 950px wide. Then I'll look for a CSS coder to help me rewrite the pages getting rid of all the tables.

Answer (score 0):

As Marc and Fez pointed out, tables should really only be used for data display.

I propose you use div elements to achieve your goal, like this:

```
<body>

    <div>Some Text</div>
    <div class="coloured">Some Text</div>
    <div>Some Text</div>
    <div class="coloured">Some Text</div>

</body>
```

Take a look at this [JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fZnyN/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `<div>` based solution that also takes advantage of CSS3 selector.

In the past tables were used for layout, but they are very tedious and fragile for that purpose. As metioned in other responses, tables are meant to display data.

**HTML**

Place this directly in `<body>`

```
<div class="zebra">
    <div class="zebra-item">
        <div class="zebra-left">
            Some text
        </div>
        <div class="zebra-right">
            Some image
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="zebra">
    <div class="zebra-item">
        <div class="zebra-left">
            Some image
        </div>
        <div class="zebra-right">
            Some text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

Notice the `.zebra:nth-of-type(2n)` selector here. That makes sure every other element has a grey background. No need to insert extra classes.

```
.zebra:nth-of-type(2n) {
    background-color: #efefef;
}

.zebra-item {
    width:400px;
    clear:left;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

.zebra-left, .zebra-right {
    width: 50%;
    float:left;
}
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5sE34/).